# What are the disadvantages of thread-per-connection model?

Tags: multithreading, network-programming, language-agnostic, distributed-computing, distributed-system

One of the points of the [Distributed Systems Prayer](http://pl.atyp.us/2014-10-dist-sys-prayer.html) stands:

> I have implemented a thread-per-connection model

I have the following questions regarding this statement:

1. What are the disadvantages of this model when designing a server/distributed system?
2. What approach would work better in most cases?
3. In what cases it may be the right approach?

Comment: 1. Scalability, although such systems have been built that handle 100,000s of connections so it really isn't the issue it is painted to be. 2. This one. 3. All but the most severe. Your link is amusing but unscientific.

Comment: A thread is far too expensive to keep occupied with a connection that has a latency measured in multiple milliseconds and in general only needs to be serviced in seconds.  Smart way to do it is to only use a thread when the connection has work to do, IOCP is the way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

1. What are the disadvantages of this model when designing a server/distributed system?

If your implementation language imposes a minimum value for the stack size allocated to the thread, then you run out of memory if you have large numbers of connections. Also creating many short-lived threads has a cost.

You also may have performance or reliability issues with many threads attempting to access shared data, or if your OS doesn't integrate networking events to thread wakeup.

2. What approach would work better in most cases?

In most cases it works fine - most system have enough memory for ~10,000 simultaneous clients ( or ~1,000 on Windows if you don't bother setting the stack size for the threads and leave it to 1MiB).

Asynchronous event driven libraries can be used instead, which allow a pool of N threads to handle M connections. Just using a thread pool to create the thread saves the cost of creating them, but does nothing to prevent memory starvation for a large number of clients.

3. In what cases it may be the right approach?

It's almost never the technically 'best' approach, but sometimes makes pragmatic engineering sense.

Historically, languages didn't provide simple libraries for creating thread pools or using asynchronous sockets. If you are using such a language, and do not expect to get many connections, and the connections tend to stay connected for longer times, then it is not worth the developer resource to invest in a technically better solution.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the disadvantages of this model when designing a
>   server/distributed system?

One connection = one thread. This impact the scalability of the server as the number of connections may grow significantly above the ideal amount of thread of your system.

> What approach would work better in most cases?

thread pool of executors. the task to be done for each connection (if any) is queued on the pool, thread complete jobs in fifo.

> In what cases it may be the right approach?

Don't know any of these cases.